# Whatsapp extended functionalities

Tags: android, events, listener, overlay, whatsapp

is it possible to put event listeners on some specific Whatsapp actions (E.g: play button when receiving an audio or click to download picture)? I want to implement a third-party app with new functions so the user can choose to play or translate the audio to text (if it cannot be played at the moment) and choose where (s)he wants to save the picture. When the user clicks on one of these buttons, an overlay shows up giving the user some options. I thought about using the Accessibility Service but I still don't think it is possible. Btw, using Android platform.

If it cannot be done, would you suggest a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not put any kind of Event Listeners to Whatsapp Application. The events are broadcasted by application only, you are not allowed to listen to any event from the second app unless that Application allows you to. I'm sure you would have got this idea after learning about `BroadcastReceivers` ([tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm)). But till now, WhatsApp does not provide any events for Third Party Application.

Comment: Thanks Dennis! I will have to think about sharing the media into an app and the app process it and show some feedback on screen.

Comment: Anytime mate :) Let me know if you need any help.